# Nest Panel in frame to achieve animation

Tags: java, swing

I'm trying to simulate some simple animation. Basically I would like to make a filled rectangle move across a frame. I think that what I need to do is the following.

subclass JLabel and draw my rectangle on it.

Add the JLabel to a JPanel then add this panel to a frame.

So my question is, is it possible to animate the JPanel which is invisible to give the illusion of a moving rectangle?

Answer (score 3):

Your best bet is to extend JPanel and draw in this class's paintComponent method using the Graphics object passed in as a parameter as the Swing graphics tutorials show.  Use the Graphics method drawRect to draw a rectangle outline or fillRect to draw a solid rectangle.  You'll want to use a Swing Timer to increment some int class fields that you would use in the methods above to tell paintComponent where to draw the rectangles.

Comment: One slight point.  Often a `JComponent` is entirely sufficient to do custom animation.  A `JPanel` is only required if it is intended to add other components into the rendered area.  (If you decide to alter your answer to reflect that, I'll delete this comment.)

Comment: @Andrew: you're right. I usually paint with JPanel, perhaps it's what I'm used to. I also like setting the background color via setBackground rather than having to fill a rectangle.

Comment: Actually I'm drawing a "car" I just simplified it to a rectangle. So I'm going to have a rectangle and two ovals for the wheels.

Comment: @HFOE At first I did not understand what you meant about the BG color.  A quick test supports that even if the BG color of a `JComponent` is set, and the `JComponent` is opaque, and `super.paintComponent()` is called, the BG does not get automatically rendered (as it would in a `JPanel`).  You (or perhaps more accurately, me) learns something new every day.  ;)

Comment: @Andrew: it's not much more than a convenience sort of thing, since I'm sure that JPanels draw their background by filling a rectangle via either fillRect or probably more likely clearRect.

Answer (score 1):

> Actually I'm drawing a "car" I just simplified it to a rectangle.

1. Create an Icon that represents the car
2. add the Icon to a JLabel
3. add the label to a panel
4. animate the car by changing the location of the label.

So the custom painting is contained in the Icon. This way when the car is moved from locationA to locationB, only the old and new location will be repainted.

If you attempt to do the drawing on a panel you will either end up:

1. repainting the entire panel
2. add custom code to determine which areas to repaint.